# Dropdown logic using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have three dropdowns in my html page using bootstrap,i want to display the content of second dropdown in relation to first one.

Supposedly an option 3 is chosen from five options in dropdown 1 it should not be visible in dropdown 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the change event of the first dropDown to a function responsible of dynamically change the content of the second drop down. For more explanation you have to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will remove options with the same name as in your example.
I'd use a switch for all variations.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var option = $(this).text();
  $(".dropdown-menu li a:contains('"+option+"')").css("display","none");
  //remember to handle what should be visible as well
});
```